# Moving data from c sharp to html table to email

Tags: c#, html

here's the scenario:
I am retrieving data from multiple databases and saving it in lists and dictionaries. I then have to create a table in the body of a html file that will be used as an automatically generated email with different sets of data in the table for every recipient. My question is how to add cells to the table from my main loop in the c sharp file.
Here's the c sharp code snippet:

```
foreach(string str in strList)
{
    columnOneData = someDict[Key];
    columnTwoData = str;
    columnThreeData = otherDict[Key];
    columnFourData = thirdDict[Key];
}
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("some.server.com ");
string Body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:path\HTMLPage.htm");
Body=Body.Replace("firstColData",columnOneData);
Body=Body.Replace("secondColData",columnTwoData);
Body=Body.Replace("thirdColData",columnThreeData);
Body=Body.Replace("fourthColData",columnFourData);

message.Body = Body;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SmtpServer.Send(message);
```

And here is the code in the HTML file

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="font-family:Calibri;color:Black;">
        <tr>
            <th>Column One Header</th>
            <th>Column Two Header</th>
            <th>Column Three Header</th>
            <th>Column Four Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>#firstColDataa#</td>
            <td>#secondColData#</td>
            <td>#thirdColData#</td>
            <td>#fourthColData#</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So what I am looking for are ideas to keep filling the table instead of ending up with only the data from the last iteration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to consider using some templating engine? https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine works great.

Comment: Why not use a ready templating solution? T4 templates are integrated to Visual Studio and .NET, for example. Just create a runtime template and you can fill in the data very easily.

Comment: Ok maybe I sould mention I'm quite a noob in visual studio and I don't quite understand that template

Comment: @adt Unfortunately I can not use any open source code

Comment: @Luaan I had a look at the templates. So I'm supposed to write the template so that it generates the HTML file that I will be using to send the message right? I'm sorry if I sound confusing but I am quite confused myself.

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD You want the runtime template - that will allow you to execute the template in runtime with the data you get. You'll find plenty of samples everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a quick way of doing this, placed a #tablestring# variable in the html file and then in the cs loop I just concatenated the string with every iteration as such:

```
foreach(string str in strList)
{
columnOneData = someDict[Key];
columnTwoData = str;
columnThreeData = otherDict[Key];
columnFourData = thirdDict[Key];
tablestring += "<tr><td>"+columnOneData+"</td><td>"+columnTwoData....+"</td></tr>";
}
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("some.server.com ");
string Body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:path\HTMLPage.htm");
Body=Body.Replace("tablestring",tablestring);
```

And in the html file

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="font-family:Calibri;color:Black;">
    <tr>
        <th>Column One Header</th>
        <th>Column Two Header</th>
        <th>Column Three Header</th>
        <th>Column Four Header</th>
    </tr>
    #tablestring#
</table>
```